# How to get selected text with format/style from Eclipse editors?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I use `ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().getSelection();` to get selected text in Eclipse editors like Java editor, XML editor, etc., but the returned selection is an instance of `TextSelection`, and `getText()` method just return plain text, so I want to know how to get the text and all **formats**/**style** together with text like Java syntax highlighting, etc. returned?

Comment: What sort of information are you looking for here? It might be possible to get the `StyleRange` information from the active editor, but that is just going to give you fonts and colors.

Comment: I am looking for some things like RTF or other markup languages, that is to say, rather than just return plain text, can I get the text/selection in markup language that is to represent it's style(fonts, color, etc.) in Eclipse Editor? So I can convert this marked text/selection to other formats e.g. HTML, and can also keep it's style. Can this be achieved?

Comment: For `StyleRange`, I tried  <br/>
`IEditorPart editor = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().getActiveEditor();  <br/>
StyledText text = (StyledText) editor.getAdapter(Control.class);`  <br/>
But `text` here is null, and is there a easier way to serve this purpose?

Comment: `HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event)` is enough to get the active editor. Are you sure you have the correct `Control.class` imported because `getAdapter(Control.class)` works for me (should be `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control`). `StyledText` does not do RTF or any markup langage.

Comment: You are right!!!, wrong Control.class was imported. `StyleRange` works now. I will do an evaluation on this. Thank you!